# How to set SPF Record when using the MailApp service at AdWords Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

How do we have to to set SPF Record when using the MailApp service at AdWords Scripts?
We use our own email address as sender address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add Google's SPF record: `_spf.google.com`.  So, at a minimum your SPF record should look a bit like this:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```